# Pyspark Error facing on low frequency categories combining code

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Now I am getting another error while creating udf function in pyspark.
Merchant Category Code field in my data is very high dimensional.I want to reduce its categories. 
My Approach for all categories of this field with count less than 1000. I want to assign new category (MCC_lowcount).

But its throwing below error at last line of below code

```
Error: TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: 1000 of type <class 'int'>. 
For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

Code:

```
def cut_levels(x, threshold, new_value):
        value_counts = x1.value_counts()
        labels = value_counts.index[value_counts < threshold]
        x[np.in1d(x, labels)] = new_value
    udf_cut_levels=udf(cut_levels,StringType())
    udf_cut_levels(df1['Merchant Category Code'], 1000, 'MCC_lowcount')
```

Comment: # this code working in pandas for combining low frequency categories
     df.loc[df['Merchant Category Code'].isin((df['Merchant Category Code'].value_counts()[df['Merchant Category Code'].value_counts() < 1000]).index), 'Merchant Category Code'] = 'other'
   ## now when I am using same function in pyspark in udf format then its giving error.
   def test(df,x):
      df.loc[df[x].isin((df[x].value_counts()[df[x].value_counts() < 1000]).index),x] = 'MCC_lowcount'
      return ''
     udf_test=udf(test,StringType())
    df1=udf_test(df1,'Merchant Category Code')

Comment: Error:  TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: DataFrameDataFrame'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.